# sed command : unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed

Please help with below error.

```
virt01@virt01:~$ awk '{print $4}' run.list  | sed "s/[deployer@/''/g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
virt01@virt01:~$ awk '{print $4}' run.list  | sed 's/"[deployer@"/''/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
virt01@virt01:~$ awk '{print $4}' run.list  | sed 's/"[deployer@"//g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
virt01@virt01:~$
```

Thank you.

Comment: The bracket needs to be escaped: `"s/\[deployer@/''/g"`.

Comment: Please add it as answer. I will accept.cause you saved valuable time today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is a character of special significance in a regular expression. Thus, as any special character in regexp, it needs to be escaped:

```
"s/\[deployer@/''/g"
```